# Facebook Error in Android "Login failed: com.facebook.android.DialogError: The connection to the server was unsuccessful"

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am using facebook in my app to publish data to facebook.  But when i tried the examples which is given in the android sdk for facebook.  It give me this error
"DEBUG/Facebook-authorize(749): Login failed: com.facebook.android.DialogError: The connection to the server was unsuccessful"

Thanks,
     aby

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this problem occured due to many request send to facebook from android.  It started working on the next day.

Comment: I think it was because your application hadn't propagated and 'created' itself on all servers.

Comment: It is working or not on strange way. 2 hours , one hour not, 4 hours working, 3 not :(. Users say:"Facebook app is working - so it is your fault" :(

Answer (score 0):

I was getting "The connection to the server was unsuccessful" on my device, while the AVD worked fine. Clear cache with Android Browser -> Settings -> Clear Cache. Fixed this for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on an Android Phone, try rebooting the phone, that worked for me.